# TypeError for __init__()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a nutrition calculator and I'm having a bit of issues regarding **init**().

```
    def main():
        print "Welcome to the MACRONUTRIENT CALCULATOR"
        User_nutrition = get_data()     
        User_nutrition.calorie_budget()


    class get_data(object):
        def __init__(self, calorie_deficit):
            self.calorie_deficit = calorie_deficit
        def calorie_bugdet(self):                                   # ask for calorie deficit
            self.calorie_deficit = float(input("Enter you calorie deficit: "))



    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I get an error:

```
           TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

However, when I look at a documentation example I see that

```
    class Complex:
        def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
           self.r = realpart
           self.i = imagpart
```

Is fine! I'm a bit confused. I know that **init**(self) sort of helps initializes the object and allocates space for it in memory but ahat is all that I know about it. Am I missing any other information about **init** and self that I should know about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
User_nutrition = get_data()   # one argument self
# and
def __init__(self, calorie_deficit): # two arguments
```

You should do

```
User_nutrition = get_data(5) # add one argument
# or
def __init__(self, calorie_deficit = 0): # make one argument default
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `__init__` doesn't allocate space for the object in memory, that is customized by `__new__`. The instance has already been created by the point `__init__` is called. In this case, you accept two parameters:

```
class get_data(object):
    def __init__(self, calorie_deficit):
        self.calorie_deficit = calorie_deficit
```

The first is the instance (which is implicitly passed), so the only argument you need to pass is `calorie_deficit`. However in your `main()` call:

```
User_nutrition = get_data()
```

You don't pass that argument, so only the instance has been passed. Hence the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```