# Simple guestbook django: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and trying to make a simple guestbook application to get used to the environment. I get the following mistake, but I can't locate the error:

**Exception Value: _*init*_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

class Bericht(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    inhoud = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    datum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.auteur) + " : " + str(self.titel)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "berichten"

class BerichtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["auteur", "datum", "titel"]
    list_filter = ["datum", "auteur"]

admin.site.register(Bericht, BerichtAdmin)
```

The view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from Gastenboek.models import *

class BerichtListView(ListView):
    model = Bericht.objects.all()
    template_name = 'template/bericht_lijst.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = "bericht_lijst"
# Create your views here.
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Niels.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r"^(\d+)/$", 'Gastenboek.views.BerichtListView'),
    (r"", 'Gastenboek.views.BerichtListView'),
)
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 3.3.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Gastenboek')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I think your problem from     model = Bericht.objects.all() , it should be     model = Bericht or your urls not adding .as_view()

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835651/typeerror-for-init/16835734#16835734 The issue can be quite similar.

Answer (score 251):

In your urls.py:

You are missing .as_view()

change it to:

```
(r"^(\d+)/$", Gastenboek.views.BerichtListView.as_view()),
(r"", Gastenboek.views.BerichtListView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Now I get an error saying Gastenboek is not defined

Comment: When I do: from Gastenboek import * , it says that there is no module named site.

Comment: You shouldn't use wildcards... try import Gastenboek.views.BerichtListView

Comment: @Alvaro, You just saved me a lot of headaches, thank you!

Comment: @GED125 glad this is still useful :)